# How to retrieve data from Stack Exchange API with user authentication?

Tags: stackexchange-api

Currently I'm working a project which needs to retrieve Stack Overflow questions to analyze them. First I started to retrieve data without creating an authentication token.

```
response = requests.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")
```

But I found out that I can access to API with an authorization token. So I created an account. But I cannot understand w how to retrieve the data with authorization token. I read authentication details but I couldn't figure that out. Can any one explain me the process to get the data with using authorization token?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need an API key. This increases the number of requests you can do per day (**quota**) from 300 to 10000 and if often helpful to scripts/apps that use the API a lot.

To get a key, you should [register](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) your app on StackApps. See also: [How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here](https://stackapps.com/q/7).

---

The access token (you probably confused the key with) is used to [write](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write), something you don't seem to need. See more on [how to obtain it](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and a [live example](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib).